# Use a variable in XSLT select

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to make a named template or function where I an pass in a node name and it will select that as the last level of a xpath expression.  But all it returns is the string I pass in as a param.  In the below example the value returned is "name"

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>

    <xsl:template name="get-prefered">
        <xsl:param name="field-name"/> 

        <xsl:variable name="vCondition" select="name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="x" select="sources/source[@type='C']/$field-name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$x"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="get-prefered">
            <xsl:with-param name="field-name">name</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sources>
    <source type='C'>
        <name>Joe</name>
        <age>10</age>
    </source>
    <source type='B'>
        <name>Mark</name>
        <age>20</age>
    </source>
</sources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="sources/source[@type='C']/$field-name"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="sources/source[@type='C']/*[name()=$field-name]"/>
```

it returns:

```
Joe
```

Comment: Is there also a solution when you want to pass a set of alternatives like `<xsl:with-param name="field-name">name1|name2|name3</xsl:with-param>`? It would not make much sense in this example, but I'm fighting that problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here:

```
select="sources/source[@type='C']/$field-name"
```

is that the variable `$field-name` contains a *string*, not a *location path* - so that the expression expands to:

```
select="sources/source[@type='C']/'name'"
```

If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor, then you are likely to have access to an evaluate() function that can convert a string into a path, e.g. http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/evaluate.html Otherwise you'll need to use some other method - for example, the one shown by Joel M. Lamsen in his answer.

Comment: Seems like it needs xslt 3.0 [https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.html](source)

Comment: There was no XSLT 3.0 when this answer was written.

Comment: The point was: is it available in XSLT 2.0 or just in XSLT 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your named template want to process the entire document, Then xslt is like this ...

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>

<xsl:template name="get-prefered">
    <xsl:param name="field-name"/> 

    <xsl:variable name="vCondition" select="$field-name/name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="$field-name/sources/source[@type='C']/name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$x"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="get-prefered">
        <xsl:with-param name="field-name" select="."></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to be able to pasd in the last level of the xpath (in this simplified example the only valid choices are name and age) and it return one value.